# How to convert png/jpeg to .bmp in iOS

Tags: ios, image, bmp

How can I convert png/jpeg to a .bmp image? I have tried the following solution but no luck:

```
CGImageRef sourceRef = source.CGImage;
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(sourceRef);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(sourceRef);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t bytesPerPixel    = 4;
size_t bytesPerRow      = (width * bitsPerComponent * bytesPerPixel + 7) / 8;
size_t dataSize         = bytesPerRow * height;

unsigned char *data = malloc(dataSize);
memset(data, 0, dataSize);


CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), sourceRef);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
unsigned char *bitmapData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
```

Comment: why the -vote, is this any specific reason.

Comment: Probably a .bmp hater.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242352/converting-jpeg-to-bitmap-in-ios-using-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, you need to get the .jpg into an NSBitmapImageRep object and then let the frameworks handle the conversion for you.

Below is the link For MAC:
[How to convert .jpg image to .bmp format using Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369958/how-to-convert-jpg-image-to-bmp-format-using-objective-c)

There is a commandline tool which might help you from GITHUB

https://github.com/tonybeltramelli/TMXResolutionTool/

Also the best thing would be to get the image in UIImage and then convert it to bitMap.

https://github.com/PaulSolt/UIImage-Conversion

This will help you.

Regards,

Anil

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i am lookingcon iphone end not for mac

Comment: Get new UIImage and then convert it.